# ngAfterContentChecked and ngAfterViewChecked not displaying correct value until after 2nd event

Tags: angular, angular-grid

I have angular 2 code which displays a grid with a number of fields, each field has a filter. I want to display the number of items returned when a filter is run. I do this by counting the number of rows currently on the screen and use ngAfterViewChecked() to get the number once it changes. The issue i am facing, the correct number is only displayed after the 2nd event happens. For example, in the below picture, 1 item is returned from the filter but it says 'Showing 11 users of 13 in total'. However, if i click the mouse or press a key that will change it to 'Showing 1 users of 13 in total'. I have also tried to use ngAfterContentChecked()

[image]

```js
ngAfterViewChecked() : void {

        this.numOfUsersOnPage = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-datatable-even").length;
        this.changeDetection.detectChanges();

}
```

```html
<div class="grid-padding">
        <span *ngIf="showNumOfUser"> Showing {{numOfUsersOnPage}} users of {{totalNumOfUsers}} in total </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you doing manual change detection instead binding to models and events and the let Angular do it's thing?

Comment: i added this into the html code : 

<span *ngIf="showNumOfUser"
              [ngModel]="numOfUsersOnPage"
              (ngModelChange)="test1($event)"
            > Showing {{numOfUsersOnPage}} users of {{totalNumOfUsers}} in total </span>

but i get an error saying - No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute